# Common ground between Deck and Graveyard in trading card games

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

I am developing a Trading Card Game and I am in need to extract functionality from two of my classes as they are both doing almost the same.

it is about the Deck and Graveyard constructs which are visible on the field. The Deck is where the cards are which you can still draw, the Graveyard is where your used cards are.

What word could I use to describe both a Deck and a Graveyard, Stack is already taken unfortunately (by the Java language) and I'd personally describe it as a Pile, but not sure if that is the best wording.

Comment: Since another word for *"graveyard"* is *"discard pile"*, I think *"pile"* is an excellent choice.

Comment: A "heap" of cards? A "collection" of cards? An "assortment" of cards? A "selection" of cards...

Comment: I might suggest CardStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pile` is exactly the correct word, used in the [written rules](http://www.pagat.com/) for hundreds of card games.